# Text effect iteration

Tags: javascript, css, text, jquery-effects

I have used this example :
http://jsfiddle.net/37usj/3/

```
Next();  maybe I should change Next() function but I don't Know the way
```

but I would like to change it in order to repeat the effect but without adding the text over and over again.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Please clarify.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "repeat the effect but without adding the text over and over again", because that's essentially what repeating is - doing something over and over again.

Comment: I want to set in text "BREAKING NEWS" the fadein effect but infinitely but without doing that "BREAKING NEWS BREAKING NEWS "BREAKING NEWS ....: . When the text ends, I want to erase the text and start fadein typing again.

Comment: you could do this with animation CSS and a pseudo element http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/vEVXaJ if that's an answer, i'll make it so :)